# How do I check that dates from one range are not in another range?

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I have such the task: there are assets (computer, printer and so on) that departments can reserve for themselves. Naturally, booking dates can't overlap. I wrote the method that accepts a set assets and date. I Check this date with the dates of already existing reservations and, if it falls into an already active reservation, then I throw an error to the user that the date is busy. If it doesn't fit, I'll reserve it for that date. The problem is that method is currently not working correctly and doesn't take into account all the options. For example, department has reserved an asset from 27.10.2022 to 27.10.2022. While another department will be able to reserve the same asset from 26.10.2022 to 28.10.2022. This logic is wrong.

Please help me implement this method correctly.

```
public boolean isDateWithinRangeAssetReservations(Set<Asset> assets, Date checkDate) {

    Date checkDateWithTruncate = DateUtils.truncate(checkDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String query = "select e from am_AssetReservation e where e.refAsset IN :assets and (:checkDate between e.dateFrom and e.dateTo) and e.isActive = true";
    List<AssetReservation> assetReservations = dataManager.load(AssetReservation.class)
            .query(query)
            .parameter("assets", assets)
            .parameter("checkDate", checkDateWithTruncate)
            .list();
    return !assetReservations.isEmpty();
```

```
Above is the implementation of my method whose logic is not working properly
```

Comment: you would need another condition added to your query, how else?

Comment: Could you be more specific about, what you mean?

Comment: you have put one condition about the timestamp in it; clearly, you need to put in two

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand how to do it right. Need to add another date to the method to check? Can you please tell me how the request should look like?

Comment: either you wrote this code and should understand pretty well what I'm saying, or you should be asking the person who did write the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to rewrite query to use >= and <= conditions, instead of "between".
Also, change the "eclipselink.sql" logger to DEBUG level to view real SQL issued to the database. It will make the situation clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tell me, in what place to specify as level DEBUG? Instead "INFO" or "WARN"?
<logger name="eclipselink" level="WARN"/>

 <logger name="eclipselink.sql" level="INFO"/>

Comment: To logback.xml if you have this file in your project. Also you can go to Administration -> Server Log screen and change this level in runtime. If I write "eclipselink.sql" then I mean "eclipselink.sql" and not "eclipselink" :)